# Django - CPF ou CNPJ

Tags: python, django

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Como forma de aprendizado estou criando um sistema no Django com cadastro de Clientes.

Alguém poderia me ajudar na lógica para que no cadastro eu possa escolher CPF ou CNPJ.

Minha Models está assim atualmente:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    nome_fantasia = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    cliente_classificacao = models.ForeignKey(ClienteClassificacao, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cliente_situacao = models.ForeignKey(ClienteSituacao, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_fantasia
```

e o meu forms está assim:

```
class ClienteForm(ModelForm):
    cep = BRZipCodeField(max_length=9)

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = ['razao_social', 'nome_fantasia', 'cliente_classificacao', 'cliente_situacao',
                  'cep', 'endereco', 'numero', 'bairro', 'municipio', 'estado']
```

A minha intenção é no ato do cadastro selecionar a classificação do cliente e conforme a classificação o formulário já mudar a mascara do campo.

Grato

Comment: Você pode fazer isso de forma automática com ajax, analisando com um if onde que até 11 caracteres seja mapeado com a estrutura de CPF (XXX.XXX.XXX-XX), caso ultrapasse este valor, limitado a 14 considere a formatação do CNPJ (XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX). Lembrando que, é ótimo colocar a validação do cálculo para verificação destes números. Segue abaixo o manual de cálculo: CPF: https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/algoritmo-para-validar-cpf/
CNPJ: http://www.macoratti.net/alg_cnpj.htm

Comment: Por favor, idente corretamente o código.  
Cole o código aqui, como vem do editor de texto, e use o botão `{}` para formatar.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @EmilioEijiInaba na verdade o django não faz isso - tem que ser feito via javascript no navegador, e não tem um objeto pronto do django para gerar esse código